# IBuildCoverage not recognized in a tfs build custom activity

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, code-coverage, tfsbuild

In Build process I want to add a custom activity that calculates code Coverage rates.
However even if I add **Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client** assembly to my reference, VS2012 does not recognize IBuildCoverage. 
Can any one help me please.

Comment: which tool is being used for code coverage in your custom activity?

Comment: I use code coverage of vs 2012 premium